# Two questions on homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Say I have a $\alpha: G \to H$.

1. What do I have to do to prove that $\alpha$ is a homomorphism? I thought it was just show $\alpha(g_1g_2) = \alpha(g_1)\alpha(g_2)$. But someone told me today that I also have to show $\alpha(g^{-1}) = \alpha(g)^{-1}$. Is this the case and if so why?
2. Why is $\alpha(g^{-1}) = \alpha(g)^{-1}$?

Comment: Homomorphism...of what? Groups, rings, algebras...?

Comment: You only need to show $\,\alpha(g_1\cdot g_2)=\alpha(g_1)*\alpha(g_2)\,$, if we're talking of groups $\,(G,\cdot)\,,\,(H,*)\,$

Comment: Set $g_2=e_G$ and you find $\alpha(e_G)=e_H$. Then set $g_2=g_1^{-1}$ and you have your implication.

Answer (score 10):

If $G$ and $H$ are groups and you know that $\alpha(g_1)\alpha(g_2)=\alpha(g_1g_2)$ for all $g_1$ and $g_2$, then it will *necessarily* be true that $\alpha(g^{-1})=\alpha(g)^{-1}$. Proving this is an interesting exercise (hint: prove first that $\alpha(e_G)=e_H$).

Because of this implication, it doesn't matter whether one requires of a homomorphism only that $\alpha(g_1)\alpha(g_2)=\alpha(g_1g_2)$, or additionally $\alpha(g^{-1})=\alpha(g)^{-1}$. Both definitions make "homomorphism" mean *the same* class of maps, and you can find both of them in different texts.

The reason why one would ever want to include the "superfluous" $\alpha(g^{-1})=\alpha(g)^{-1}$ (or $\alpha(e_G)=e_H$) in a definition is that the longer definition can be constructed systematically as "everything you can do in a group must be preserved by the map" -- and there are three things you can do in a group, namely compose elements, take inverses, and find the identity element. This maps naturally to a three-part definition of "homomorphism", and generalizes smoothly to what "homomorphism" means for algebraic structures other than groups.

Comment: What a nice answer. ${}{}$

Comment: I, personally, like the way you solved the problem. I mean your point of views here. +1

Answer (score 4):

That someone told you wrong.

To prove that $\alpha: G \to G^{\prime}$ is a homomorphism between groups $(G,\,\cdot)$ and ($G^{\prime},\,*)$, you need to prove $\alpha(g_1\cdot g_2) = \alpha(g_1)*\alpha(g_2)$.  You *do not also* need to prove $\alpha(g^{-1}) = \alpha(g)^{-1}$.

But it *is* true that for all homomorphisms $\alpha: G \to G^{\prime}$,

- $\alpha(e) = e^{\prime}$, where $e$ is the identity of $G$ and $e^{\prime}$ is the identity of $G^{\prime}$, and with this,
- it can also be proven that $\alpha(g^{-1}) = \alpha(g)^{-1}$ for $g\in G$.
- Furthermore, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $\alpha[G]$ is a subgroup of $G^{\prime}$, and
- if $K$ is a subgroup of $G^{\prime}$, then $\alpha^{-1}[K]$ is a subgroup of $G$.

In other words, a homomorphism $\alpha: G \to G^{\prime}$ maps identity to identity, inverses to inverses, and subgroups to subgroups.

But each of the above properties are *necessarily* implied by the property that defines a homomorphism: if you can show: $$\alpha(g_1\cdot g_2) = \alpha(g_1)*\alpha(g_2)$$ then you will have proven $\alpha: G \to G^{\prime}$ is a homomorphism between groups $(G,\,\cdot)$ and ($G^{\prime},\,*)$. The properties bulleted above then *follow*.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you mean for $G$ and $H$ to be groups. You don't have to check $\alpha(g^{-1})=\alpha(g)^{-1}$ as it follows from the multiplicative property:

\begin{gather*}
\alpha(g^{-1})\alpha(g)=\alpha(g^{-1}g)=\alpha(e_G)=e_H\\
\alpha(g)\alpha(g^{-1})=\alpha(gg^{-1})=\alpha(e_G)=e_H\\
\end{gather*}

Then $\alpha(g^{-1})=\alpha(g)^{-1}$ by uniqueness of inverses.

(Note that $\alpha(e_G)=e_H$ follows by a similar argument, using the multiplicative property, and uniqueness of identity).

Answer (score 2):

Set $g_2=e_G$ and you find $\alpha(e_G)=e_H$. Then set $g_2=g_1^{-1}$ and you have your implication.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $\alpha:G\to H$ is a group homomorphism if for all $x,y\in G$ we have $\alpha(xy)=\alpha(x)\alpha(y)$.

Now let $1_G$ be the identity element of $G$. Then $\alpha(1_G)=1_H\cdot\alpha(1_G)=(\alpha(1_G)^{-1}\cdot\alpha(1_G))\cdot\alpha(1_G)=\alpha(1_G)^{-1}\cdot\alpha(1_G)\alpha(1_G)=\alpha(1_G)^{-1}\cdot\alpha(1_G\cdot1_G)=\alpha(1_G)^{-1}\cdot\alpha(1_G)=1_H.$

That is, $\alpha$ automatically maps the identity of $G$ to the identity of $H$.

For any $x\in G$ we then have $\alpha(x)\alpha(x^{-1})=\alpha(x\cdot x^{-1})=\alpha(1_G)=1_H$ by the above; this shows that $\alpha(x^{-1})$ is inverse to $\alpha(x)$, and by uniqueness of inverses (I guess you have shown that / had that in the respective group axiom), $\alpha(x^{-1})=\alpha(x)^{-1}$.

So 2. is a property that already follows from the definition of a group homomorphism, hence you don't have to show it separately.